# Array Variable base type

Tags: java

While declaring the Array variable in Java

```
Int Myarray [];
```

we have already declared the base type as int (in the above example).

then why do we have to define the type again while using new.

```
Myarray = new int[12];
```

why cant it be like the following

`Myarray = new[12]`

//because we already know that the base type of this array will be int.

Comment: List<Integer> []ar = new ArrayList[20];

Comment: Two thoughts on your code style:

a) You didn't declare the array's type as primitive `int`, but as an object of class `Int` - which is a class from java.awt. Just in case you were not aware.

There is a non primitive `Integer`, though. You wouldn't need that with arrays. Unless you know why you're using the boxed `Integer`, you should prefer an `int` - java knows autoboxing and automatically converts between primitives and the boxed types where needed:

`List<Integer> myList = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3);`

b) Variable names in Java by covnention start with lower case letters: `myArray`.

Comment: thanks and ignore my syntax error please, just started learning the language...:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Traditionally, Java has been verbose. Recent versions have attempted to favour brevity by following the "Don't Repeat Yourself" (DRY) principle. For example, in Java 6, you would write:

```
List<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>();
```

but Java 7 allows:

```
List<String> myList = new ArrayList<>();
```

The same is not true for arrays. That's because, for reasons of backward compatibility with an initial poor design decision, you can do:

```
Object[] myArray = new String[10];
```

Mistreating `myArray` can now lead to an `ArrayStoreException`. But the fact remains that you can declare and initialise `myArray` as above because Java 1.0 allowed it and later versions had to be compatible. So now, we can't write

```
Animal[] myArray = new [10];
```

because the compiler doesn't know whether we wanted to initialise it with a `Dog[10]` or a `Cat[10]`.

Java 10 offers the `var` keyword for initialising local variables, which means you don't have to repeat the type name:

```
var myArray = new int[10];
```

Here `myArray` has the compile-time type `int[]`. The compiler allows us to do all `int`-array operations on `myArray` just as though we had declared it as `int[]`, because that's exactly what it is.

Answer (score 1):

Because java was conceived to be a strongly typed language.

If you want to make assignements without specifying the type of the assigned content knowing that anyway it will work at runtime, you can do in other languages like, in particular, javascript.

Answer (score 1):

Because you also might declare array variable as Object

```
Object array = new int[12];
```

In Java10+ in methods (for local variables) you can use

```
var myArray = new int[12];
```

Answer (score 0):

Give an example:

```
public interface Animal {

}

public class Cat implements Animal {

}

public class Dog implements Animal {

}
```

**Then:**

```
Animal animal;
animal = new ???
```

`new` What? `Cat` or `Dog`

Comment: @yunandtidus hmmm, yes or `Animal`.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: because.

Longer answer: because Java was designed that way. Java usually prefers verbosity over ambiguity. As java classes are polymorphic, it might not always be clear what type to instantiate. Imagine something like this:

`Comparable[] myArray = new[22];`

Given this you should also know that at runtime Java arrays are untyped, so under certain circumstances an array might contain objects that don't fit to the arrays element type.

There is something that comes close to what you have in mind in java 10. In some cases you might infer the type like:

`var myArray = new int[22];`

You should be careful with that, though.